# Oracle trigger compiling but nothing happening?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I am attempting to make a trigger that counts the rows added to a table after insertion. The trigger compiles and throws no errors, but there is nothing in my counter table showing my count.

Here is my test table structure:

```
create table gene_presence(genome_id VARCHAR2(20), gene_id VARCHAR2(15), primary key(genome_id,gene_id) );
```

Here is my code to make a table and the trigger to increase and decrease as that table (gene_presence) is updated:

```
CREATE TABLE genes_in_genomes(
    gene_id varchar2(15),
    counter number (30));

INSERT INTO genes_in_genomes select count(*) as gene_count, gene_id as gene
from gene_presence
group by gene_id;

select * from genes_in_genomes; 

create or replace trigger gene_in_genome_counter after insert on gene_presence
for each row
begin 
    update genes_in_genomes set counter= counter+1 
    where gene_id= :new.gene_id;
end;
/
create or replace trigger gene_in_genome_dec after update on gene_presence
for each row
begin
    update genes_in_genomes set counter=counter-1 
    where gene_id=:old.gene_id;
    update genes_in_genomes set counter= counter+1 
    where gene_id=:new.gene_id;
end; 
/
```

Then I insert data into gene_presence:

```
insert into gene_presence values('1072459.4', 'group_10297');
insert into gene_presence values('1411691.4',   'group_10297');
insert into gene_presence values('316407.9',    'group_10297');
insert into gene_presence values('316407.41',   'group_10297');
```

And attempt to check what is in genes_in_genomes:

```
select * from GENES_IN_GENOMES;
```

And get an empty table. Thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

Using triggers to updates counts, or maintain any agregate, is almost always the wrong thing. Use views, materialized views if select of count needs to be fast.

Your trigger only has `update` statements. If the `gene_id` matching `:new.gene_id` does not exist in `genes_in_genomes` then the `update` will update zero rows. An `update` of zero rows is not an error.

Use `merge` to upsert into `genes_in_genomes`.

Responding to comment asking about a view:

```
CREATE VIEW genes_in_genomes AS
SELECT gene_id varchar2(15), COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM gene_presence
GROUP BY gene_id;
```

Comment: I completely agree with you. I had a project partner who insisted on it being a trigger. How would you recommend doing this as a view?

Comment: First, dump your partner ;)